# Finding the tangent vector to a surface in 3D space

Tags: vectors

Consider the surface $:$ $()=−ℎ(,)=0$, where $ℎ(,)$ is an arbitrary single-valued continuous and differentiable function of  and

For the specific function $h(x,y)=\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2}$ we make a sketch in the plane $y=0$

[image]

where i have drawn one of the two distinct vectors which are locally tangent to $$ at each point $(,)=++ℎ(,)$ lying on

I was wondering where the other tangent vector be $t_y$

Would it coming out (or in) of the page or does it exists since y=0

Comment: You should not say "the other", as there are an infinity of tangent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The gradient at any point of the surface is

$$(-h_x,-h_y,1)$$

(partial derivatives) and any vector orthogonal to it is tangent to the surface.

E.g. $(1,0,h_x)$ and $(h_y,-h_x,0)$. Notice that for $y=0$, $h_y=0$.